# Using one ? to contain several variables in PHP MySQLi prepared INSERT statement

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

Trying to get to grips with prepared statements for an INSERT query. This is supposed to add a new user to the database:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,passwordhash) VALUES (?)");
$statement->bind_param('s', "'$email','$passwordhash'");
$statement->execute();
```

Is it correct to use a single ? and fill it with two values in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way mysqli doing that you need to bind all the variables separately

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,passwordhash) VALUES (?,?)");
$statement->bind_param('ss', $email,$passwordhash);
$statement->execute();
```

But if you want it your way (say, you have an array ready and want to insert it using one placeholder) you need a helper class which will translate a custom placeholder into correct SQL statement:

```
$data = array('email'=>$email, 'passwordhash'=>$passwordhash);
$db->query("INSERT INTO users SET ?u");
```

and it will be shorter than raw mysqli yet will do much more - error handling, profiling and such.

Also keep in mind that when you will have a variable number of fields to insert, mysqli will turned to be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this.

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,passwordhash) VALUES (?,?)");
$statement->bind_param('ss', $email,$passwordhash);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Don't you mean: `$statement->bind_param('ss', $email, $passwordhash);`?

Comment: Yeah I just spotted that, changed it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

In prepared statements, each `?` is used to replace one value.

When executed, your query will be:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,passwordhash) VALUES ("'email','password'")
```

That's not what you want.  You need to use 2 ?s, one for each value.

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,passwordhash) VALUES (?,?)");
// Pass each variable as a separate parameter
$statement->bind_param('ss', $email, $passwordhash);
$statement->execute();
```